# getting 404 error on wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, wamp, http-status-code-404, buddypress, migrate

I've seen some other people with the same issue on net,
but the solution that worked for them (updating the .htacess file), didn't go very well for me!

I used buddypress to migrate my wordpress site to my local pc, but after everything is setup, only the home page is working, other posts or pages are getting 404 errors, I also tried to deactivate plugins and changing the theme, but nothing worked.

I'm on windows 10 and i'm using wampserver 2.5.
I think that the issue is caused by Apache, but I don't know how to fix it!
my Apache version is 2.4.9

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: Have you changed the siteurl and home records in the database? What are your permalink settings? They might need to be changed to the default, and back again to the setting you want. (Permalinks may store the routing from the previous install location, and the URLs on the site may be incorrect.)

Comment: they are already by default, here's a simple video to show you what I'm struggling with! I don't think it has anything to do with permalinks.

Comment: https://youtu.be/1rnUROOG7HM

Answer (score 1):

Your site’s permalink (WordPress Admin > Settings > Permalink) is set as Default, please change it to any of the other option available below. e.g: Day and name, Post name etc.

Then you’ll be able to access the board instead of the 404 error.

Another way is **troubleshooting**:

WordPress sites can complicate the 404 troubleshooting process. Why? WordPress is a content management system that processes its own internal rewrite array as a part of its permalinks feature.

The first step to troubleshooting 404s is to figure out whether the 404 is being caused by the web server or by WordPress.
Static file

If your file is static (e.g. a jpg image) open your FTP client and verify that the file exists.

As an example, let’s say that the URL http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/picture.jpg is producing a 404 error. You will want to:

```
Open FTP Client and connect to your server (if you don’t know how to do so, read this.)
Navigate to the file’s location
Verify that the file exists
If it is does not exist, you have found the source of your 404.
```

However, it it does exist, yet pulling the URL up in a browser results in a 404 error, continue on to find out whether the issue is web server-based or WordPress-based.

Reference Link: http://websynthesis.com/fixing-wordpress-404-errors/

Comment: I tried to view a photo in my wordpress content , and it worked fine!